# color date 0000-00-00 and remain functions

Tags: javascript

i have a javascript that colors all dates in a table(starting from todays date) that are allready in the past green, and the dates that will expire within two weeks red. All works very fine.

```
var parents = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var parent = parents[i],
        children = parent.children

    for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
        var elem = children[j]
        if (j % 3 === 2) {
            var dateElement = elem.innerHTML;
            var dateArray = dateElement.split("-");     
            var prevTime = new Date(dateArray[0],dateArray[1]-1,dateArray[2]);
            var thisTime = new Date();
            var diff = prevTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();
            var days = 1000*60*60*24;
            var diffInDays = Math.ceil(diff / days);
            if (diffInDays < 0) {
                elem.style.color = "#008000";
            }
            else if (diffInDays <= 14) {
                elem.style.color = "#ff0000";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when i remove the products that are due or overdate, the date becomes 0000-00-00
how can i color all 0000-00-00 dates for example purple and still remain the green and red color for other dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you right the quickest way would be to just add a check in for 0000-00-00, without seeing your mark up its hard to tell

```
var parents = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var parent = parents[i],
        children = parent.children

    for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
        var elem = children[j]
        if (j % 3 === 2) {
            var dateElement = elem.innerHTML;
            var dateArray = dateElement.split("-");     
            var prevTime = new Date(dateArray[0],dateArray[1]-1,dateArray[2]);
            var thisTime = new Date();
            var diff = prevTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();
            var days = 1000*60*60*24;
            var diffInDays = Math.ceil(diff / days);
            if(dateElement === "0000-00-00"){
                elem.style.color = "purple";
            }else if (diffInDays < 0) {
                elem.style.color = "#008000";
            }
            else if (diffInDays <= 14) {
                elem.style.color = "#ff0000";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with somenthing like this?

```
function colorDate(){
var parents = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
var parent = parents[i],
    children = parent.children

for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
    var elem = children[j]
    if (j % 3 === 2) {
        var dateElement = elem.innerHTML;
        var dateArray = dateElement.split("-");     
        var prevTime = new Date(dateArray[0],dateArray[1]-1,dateArray[2]);
        var thisTime = new Date();
        var diff = prevTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();
        var days = 1000*60*60*24;
        var diffInDays = Math.ceil(diff / days);
        if (diffInDays < 0) {
            elem.style.color = "#008000";
        }
        else if (diffInDays <= 14) {
            elem.style.color = "#ff0000";
        }
        if(dateElement=="0000-00-00"){
            elem.style.color = "your color";
        }
     }
   }
}
}
colorDate();
```

and call colorDate() in remove function!